# Check credentials for SMTP server

Tags: .net, vb.net, smtp

I want to make a program to check mail and password match or not.

```
SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(email, pass)
SMTP.Send(emailMessage)
```

I can check send Ok mean match, can not send email and pass dont match.
But hope you show me better method.thanks

Comment: With _"to check mail and password match or not"_, do you mean you want to verify whether the user identified by `email` and `pass` is allowed to connect to the server specified in `SMTP` and send an email message?

Comment: If that is the case, this is a doppelgänger of [How to validate smtp credentials before sending mail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426098/how-to-validate-smtp-credentials-before-sending-mail-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check credentials without attempting a send.  If the send fails, it will throw an [SmtpException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You could check the [SmtpStatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpstatuscode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property for more detail.

Comment: This is a limit of the .NET class, not the SMTP protocol.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162932/how-can-i-sort-of-ping-an-smtp-server-so-i-can-check-if-the-account-password-i?rq=1

Comment: Do you know other method?